# Remove link to taxonomy terms $post->ID

Tags: wordpress, categories, taxonomy

how to remove the link on the categories?
this is my code

```
$taxonomy = 'casestudies_category';    
    $post_terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );
    $separator = ', ';
    if ( !empty( $post_terms ) && !is_wp_error( $post_terms ) ) {
        $term_ids = implode( ',' , $post_terms );
        $terms = wp_list_categories( 'title_li=&style=none&echo=0&taxonomy=' . $taxonomy . '&include=' . $term_ids );
        $terms = rtrim( trim( str_replace( '<br />',  $separator, $terms ) ), $separator );
        echo  $terms;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

[wp_list_categories](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) displays a list of categories as links.
If you want to get just list of categories - use [get_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)

Or describe what you want to get in result.